# StructureMap MassTransit Issue: Bi-directional dependency relationship detected

Tags: dependency-injection, rabbitmq, azure-service-fabric, structuremap, masstransit

When trying to process more than one message in quick succession using MassTransit RabbitMQ and StructureMap I get the error:

> Bi-directional dependency relationship detected!

This occurs for Consumers only, error is as follows:

> MT-Fault-ExceptionType: StructureMap.Building.StructureMapBuildException
>   MT-Fault-Message: **Bi-directional dependency relationship detected!** 
>   Check the StructureMap stacktrace below: 
>   1.) **Instance of Acme.Co.WorkerService.Consumers.SomeCommandConsumer**
>
> MT-Fault-StackTrace:  at lambda_method(Closure , IBuildSession , IContext ) 
>   at StructureMap.Building.BuildPlan.Build(IBuildSession session, IContext context) 
>   at StructureMap.SessionCache.GetObject(Type pluginType, Instance instance, ILifecycle lifecycle) 
>   at StructureMap.SessionCache.GetDefault(Type pluginType, IPipelineGraph pipelineGraph) 
>   at StructureMap.BuildSession.GetInstanceT 
>   at MassTransit.Pipeline.ConsumerFactories.DelegateConsumerFactory`1.<Send>d__2`1.MoveNext() 
>   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.<GreenPipes-IFilter<MassTransit-ConsumeContext<TMessage>>-Send>d__4.MoveNext() 
>   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.>-Send>d__4.MoveNext() 
>   at GreenPipes.Filters.TeeFilter`1.<Send>d__5.MoveNext() 
>   at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.d__7.MoveNext() 
>   at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.<SendToOutput>d__7.MoveNext() 
>   at GreenPipes.Filters.DynamicFilter`1.d__9.MoveNext() 
>   at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.d__4.MoveNext() 
>   at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.-Send>d__5.MoveNext()

I can't see any circular dependencies or bidirectional but I may be missing something.

The code for the Command Consumer is (essentially):

```
public class SomeCommandConsumer : IConsumer<ISomeCommand>
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly IAnotherRepository _anotherRepository;

    public SomeCommandConsumer(IRepository repository, IAnotherRepository anotherRepository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _anotherRepository = anotherRepository;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ISomeCommand> context)
    {
        try
        {
            await DoSomeWork(context);
            await context.Publish<ISomeProcessCompleteEvent>(new
            {
                context.Message.ID,
                SomeProperty = SomeEnum.SomeValue
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HandleException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the StructureMap registration is effectively:

```
public class WorkflowServiceRegistry : Registry
{
    public WorkflowServiceRegistry()
    {
        var configuration = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetConfigurationPackageObject(Constants.ServiceFabricConfigurationSection);
        var baseUri = configuration.Settings.Sections[Constants.ConfigurationRabbitMqConfigSection].Parameters[Constants.ConfigurationRabbitMqBaseUri].Value;
        var username = configuration.Settings.Sections[Constants.ConfigurationRabbitMqConfigSection].Parameters[Constants.ConfigurationRabbitMqUsername].Value;
        var password = configuration.Settings.Sections[Constants.ConfigurationRabbitMqConfigSection].Parameters[Constants.ConfigurationRabbitMqPassword].Value;
        var connectionString = configuration.Settings.Sections[Constants.ConfigurationDatabaseSection].Parameters[Constants.ConfigurationDatabaseConnectionString].Value;
        var dbTimeout = int.Parse(configuration.Settings.Sections[Constants.ConfigurationDatabaseSection].Parameters[Constants.ConfigurationDatabaseTimeout].Value);

        For<IAnotherRepository>().Use<AnotherRepository>();
        For<IRepository>()
            .Use<Repository>()
            .Ctor<string>()
            .Is(connectionString);
        ForConcreteType<SomethingCompleteEventConsumer>()
            .Configure
            .Ctor<string>("baseUri")
            .Is(baseUri);
        ForConcreteType<SomeCommandConsumer>();
        ForConcreteType<SomethingCompleteEventConsumeObserver>();
        For<IBusControl>().Use(container => BusConfigurator.ConfigureBus(
            baseUri,
            username,
            password,
            (cfg, host) => cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, Constants.ControllerSerivceAnalysisProcessStartQueue, SomeCommandQueueConfiguration(container)),
            (cfg, host) => cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, Constants.ControllerSerivceActionServiceCompleteQueue, SomethingCompleteEventQueueConfiguration(container))
        ));
        For<ICommunicationListener>().Use<MassTransitListener>();
    }

    private static Action<IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator> SomeCommandQueueConfiguration(IContext container)
    {
        return e =>
        {
            e.Consumer(container.GetInstance<SomeCommandConsumer>);
        };
    }

    private static Action<IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator> SomethingCompleteEventQueueConfiguration(IContext container)
    {
        return e =>
        {
            e.Consumer(container.GetInstance<SomethingCompleteEventConsumer>);
            e.Observer(container.GetInstance<SomethingCompleteEventConsumeObserver>());
        };
    }
}
```

Just wondering if this is something someone has seen before?

Note, the code is part of a service fabric solution and each service has it's own similar 'bootstrapper', or registration for StructureMap and also, some of the code is missing for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the MassTransit.StructureMap integration library, and instead of using `.Consumer(container.GetInstance<T>)` simply use `.Consumer<T>(container)`.

This will use the StructureMap scope provider, so that the consumer factory creates a nested lifetime scope for all dependencies of the consumer. You're already using the `IContext` for the builder/registration, so that should work.

Also, that isn't the way to connect an observer, at least not in the sense that should be used. There is a ConnectObserver method, which should be called prior to starting the bus. Also, observers do not have a lifetime scope on their own, but using the StructureMap scope provider will add an `ILifetimeScope` to the `ConsumeContext` payload, which can be used to resolve dependencies at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your response Chris. I'm already using the MassTransit.StructureMapIntegration library but the code you've suggested does not work, as the parameter expected is an IContainer & not an IContext. Also, as this is a Azure Service Fabric implementation, the bus is started in the MassTransitListener as part of the Service Fabric plumbing. Any suggestions on where the observers should be registered in order to do it correctly?

Comment: Well, shoot, that seems like an oversight - I was thinking of Autofac. I'll add it.